# Ejercicio matemático Javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de resolver este problema utilizando Javascript?

Se le proporciona la siguiente información:

● 1 de enero de 1900 fue un lunes.
● Treinta días tienen septiembre, abril, junio y noviembre.
● Febrero tiene veintiocho (Y en años bisiestos, veintinueve).
● El resto tiene treinta y uno.

Nota:​ Un año bisiesto ocurre en cualquier año divisible por 4, pero no en un siglo a menos que sea
divisible por 400.

> ¿Cuántos domingos cayeron el primer día del mes durante el siglo XX (1
>   de enero de 1901 a 31 de diciembre de 2000)?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta agregando todo el código que tienes por favor?

Comment: No se me ocurre como plantearlo, por eso no agregué codigo

Comment: venga que necesitas organizar los datos, realizar un análisis para definir cuál podría ser la manera de solucionarlo, los inputs: te dan fecha inicio a fecha fin, de esta data, tienes día, mes y año para ambos casos...

Comment: practica algoritmos aquí: http://www.codewars.com

Comment: @FabricioLoupias no tiene sentido que te resolvamos esto, en hackerrank (como en codewars ) también hay ejercicios de este tipo, tienes que poner en la pregunta que enfoque o que forma de solucionarlo intentaste y no te resulto. En principio, supongo que habrás pensado en como calcular cuantos días hubo en el siglo XX, por ejemplo. Y que pasó? eso no salió..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Este es mi intento, primera vez que lo hago espero que te funcione:

```js
function Calcular()
{
  //DECLARO LAS VARIABLES
  var dateInicio  = new Date("01"+' '+"January"+', '+"1901"+' 12:00:00');
  var dateFinal = new Date("31"+' '+"December"+', '+"2000"+' 12:00:00');
  var dateAux = new Date();
  var cantidadMesInicio = dateInicio.getMonth();
  var cantidadAnoInicio = dateInicio.getFullYear();
  var cantidadDias = 0;
  var cantidadDomingos = 0;
  //WHILE PARA ITERAR DESDE LA FECHA INICIO HASTA LA FECHA FINAL
  while (dateInicio <= dateFinal)
  {
    //SWITCH PARA VERIFICAR EN CUAL MES ESTA LA FECHA INICIO
    switch (cantidadMesInicio)
    {
      case (8 || 3 || 5 || 10): //SEPTIEMBRE, ABRIL, JUNIO, NOVIEMBRE
        cantidadDias = 30;
        break;
      case 1: //FEBRERO
        cantidadDias = 28;
        //IF PARA SABER SI ES AÑO BISIESTO
        if ((cantidadAnoInicio % 4 === 0 && cantidadAnoInicio % 100 !== 0) || (cantidadAnoInicio % 400 === 0))
          cantidadDias = 29;
        break;
      default:  //RESTO DE LOS MESES
        cantidadDias = 31;
        break;
    }
    //SUMO LA CANTIDAD DE DIAS A LA FECHA INICIO Y LO SETEO A UNA FECHA AUXILIAR
    dateAux.setDate(dateInicio.getDate() + cantidadDias);
    //WHILE PARA ITERAR DESDE FECHA INICIO HASTA LA FECHA AUXILIAR
    while (dateInicio <= dateAux)
    {
      //IF PARA SABER SI EL DÍA ES DOMINGO Y CAE EL PRIMER DÍA DEL MES
      if (dateInicio.getDay() === 0 && dateInicio <= dateFinal && dateInicio.getDate() === 1)
        cantidadDomingos++;
      //SUMO 1 DIA A LA FECHA INICIO Y LO SETEO A LA FECHA INICIO
      dateInicio.setDate(dateInicio.getDate() + 1);
    }
    //OBTENGO EL MES Y EL AÑO PARA CONTINUAR CON EL WHILE
    cantidadMesInicio = dateInicio.getMonth();
    cantidadAnoInicio = dateInicio.getFullYear();
  }
  alert("Cantidad de domingos: " + cantidadDomingos);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="Calcular()" value="Calcular">
```

Comment: y si lo orientan mejor a explicarle la lógica en lugar de hacerle la tarea?, SO se puede apoyar sin embargo; en la redacción propia no muestra intento alguno

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @Alfredo,  el tema de estos ejercicios es un poco aprender a pensar, si usa esto y después cambia una coma en el planteo del problema no va a saber como resolver el nuevo problema.

Comment: En realidad lo hice porque nunca lo había hecho y me llamo la atención, igual ya comente el código de acuerdo a la lógica que use. Y me gusta compartir mi código es todo.

Comment: compartir esta bien, mantente ayudando en la comunidad; pero cuando las preguntas piden ayudan con ejercicios escolares como asi luce esta publicación se pide que el OP muestre sus intentos aún cuando haya tenido errores, por que aunque le des la respuesta lo que sería mejor es que razone y con ayuda el mismo logre el resultado @VictorPerdomo

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero lo que estas resolviendo ahí es la cantidad de domingos en total, y la consigna es solo contar los domingos que sean primeros de mes nada mas (eso es lo que mas me cuesta) De todas maneras voy a tratar de modificar el código para agregar esa lógica @VictorPerdomo

Comment: Simple solo cambia if (dateInicio.getDay() === 0 && dateInicio <= dateFinal) por if (dateInicio.getDay() === 0 && dateInicio <= dateFinal && dateInicio.getDate() === 1)

Comment: Modifique este if (dateInicio.getDay() === 0 && dateInicio <= dateFinal), agregando if (dateInicio.getDay() === 0 && dateInicio <= dateFinal && dateInicio.getDate() == 01) y comprobando creo que cuenta perfecto

Answer (score -1):

Saludos amigo realmente esta sencillo tu problema no te colocare mucho codigo porque estoy desde el telefono y se me hace complicado pero tratare de que me entiendas, necesitas un bucle for y tres swich tambien necesitas saber  cuantos dias hay desde la fecha de inicio hasta la de finalizacion, 1 de enero de 1901 a 31 de diciembre de 2000 en este caso, cual es el año bisiesto mas cercano a la fecha de inicio (en el ejemplo supondre que el biciesto es la misma fecha de inicio) algunos condicionales if y las variables correctas ejem.

```
var nroDias = //total numero de dias,
nroMes=0,
nroAño=0,
diaSemana,
x=0, y=0, z=0;

for(x=1;x《=nroDias;x++){
    y++;
    z++;
    swich(y){
        case 1:diaSemana='lunes';
        break;
        case 2:diaSemana='martes';
        break;
        //y asi hasta completar los siete dias y en el dia 7 llevas la variable y =0 para que se repita el ciclo
    }
}
```

El mismo principio aplicas para encontrar el año bisiesto (if(año==4){bisiesto=si; año=0;} y los numero de mes solo aplica un poquito de logica y con un if (diaDeMes ==1 && diaSemana=='domingo'){variableQueBusco++} y todo dentro del bucle for. Suerte con lo que haces